# After connecting newer Mac Mini to monitor, the resolution is worse

Tags: macos, display, mac-mini, hdmi, resolution

I just updated from a 2014 Mac Mini to a 2020 Mac Mini for work. When the old computer was connected to this monitor, everything looked great (connected via display port).

Now when I connect the same monitor to the 2020 Mac Mini (via HDMI), it looks pixel-y, and the windows and text look a little larger than they should.

The new Mac runs Big Sur 11.3.1 and the monitor is Planar PXL 2780MW. I use software via homebrew to change the resolution mode https://github.com/jakehilborn/displayplacer

In System Preferences > Display, the resolution that the computer reports is correct for the monitor (1920x1080) and none of the other resolution options make it look any better, even after viewing the additional resolution options by pressing 'option.' I've already tried rebooting the computer and rebooting the monitor separately.
Edit: I also tried resetting the display settings using the Cmd+Opt+P+R combo on startup and that didn't help either.

I don't have any other cables on hand to check if the HDMI cable is the problem, but I just bought this one. What else can I try?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Comments are temporary, so I've edited the post to put the excellent details in the main body. Feel free to ask a second question for the keyboard issue - we have a very strongly held opinion /  custom of asking one question per question, here.

Answer (score 1):

That monitor has a native resolution of 2560 x 1440 at 27". (Same as the Apple Thunderbolt Display.)

So you should be able to achieve that resolution from your Mini. You might want to try USB-C/Thunderbolt 3 to DisplayPort, rather than HDMI. (Though it's certainly within the 4096 x 2160 pixel limit of the Mini on HDMI.)

However, it has a pixel density of 109 pixels per inch. That's half the density of 'Retina' display MacBooks, which is the standard that Apple is basing its graphics on, so you may get some lack of clarity.

I have an Apple Thunderbolt Display on a 2018 Mini, as it's still very usable.

Comment: Go for DisplayPort unless you have a very compelling reason to use HDMI is super advice.